# Print the character at a certain count in an input string without even storing the whole string

Tags: c, string

Problem - I want to print the character at the 5th position in an input string, where the user keeps typing the string any longer (s)he wants, once (s)he presses the enter key, the character present at the 5th position will get automatically printed. The key here is we don't need to store the string in memory.
I made this particular code which includes the test case part too.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define c 5
char flush()
{
int d = c;
char temp, temp1;
while(1)
{
    temp = getchar();
    if(temp == '\n')
    break;
    if(d == 0)
    temp1 = temp;
}
return temp;
}
int main()
{
int max;
char ele, pre;
scanf("%d", &max);
fflush(stdin);
ele = '\n';
while(max--)
{
    pre = ele;
    ele = flush();
    if(pre == '\n' && ele == '\n')
    break;
    printf("%c\n", ele);
}
return 0;
}
```

As far as the question looks simple, when i try coding the problem this particular way, i find it quite very tricky. how can i debug my this particular code?

Comment: OK.  Count the chars in until you reach 5, then print out the char and reset the count.  Simples..

Comment: What's the point of `d` , `c` ,`pre`,`temp1` etc when removing them does exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch=getchar();    //taking character input
    char temp;
    int i=0;              // Count the character
    while(ch!='\n')       // Stop the loop at enter
    {
        i++;
        if(i==5)
        temp=ch;     //Fifth character
        ch=getchar();
    }
    printf("%c\n",temp);
}
```

Here in above program string is not getting stored in any variable and fifth character is get printed on enter.

Comment: Edited my question, i'll be more thankful if you help me by debugging my code. :)

Comment: 1) Should use `intr ch` to distinguish `EOF` from all other `char` and then `while(ch!='\n' && ch != EOF)`  2) if `ch =='\n'` before the 5th `char`, `temp` is undefined.  Better to set it to a default value `char temp = '?';`